# Solution cannot find a projet or many projets and error say missing SDK

Tags: c#, installation, reference, sdk, .net-framework-version

I have most recent Visual Studio 2019 version and it can't load some projets.

In my cases, many solution were fine but some old solution related to .net Framework had some difficulty to find some SDK although they were all installed on my machine.

- Install missing SDK or any SDK that seems to be related does not fix the problem
- Repair VS2019 does not fix the problem
- Re-install VS2019 does not fix the problem

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, I finally found the solution:

- I'm working on a x64 machine
- At a command prompt, type: "dotnet --list-sdks", you will propably see that you are missing the SDK you expect to see and that is already installed.
- At a command prompt, type: "where dotnet", that will list all "dotnet.exe" the system can find in pathes, in order of path definition. If you have that, then this is the problem:

```
C:\>where dotnet
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe

C:\>
```

In "control panel" (old one) => "System" => "Advanced..." => "Environment Variables" => "System..." => "Path" => Ensure order of appearance of "dotnet" is "Program files" (x64) before "Program files (x86)". Note: You can move up or down the selected line.

After:

```
C:\>where dotnet
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe

C:\>
```

You should restart Visual studio (or any process) to get the newly defined environment variables.

Hope it fixes your problem!!!